# Discord JDA Bot sending messages infinitely

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to send messages using the Discord JDA API, however whenever I send one, it sends it infinitely.

JDA Version: 4.2.1_255

What I've Tried:

Research the issue
Use GuildMessageReceivedEvent instead of MessageReceivedEvent

Pseudo-Code:

```
Guild server = e.getGuild();
    Role role = server.getRolesByName("Java", false).get(0);
    System.out.println(role);
    for(Member members : server.getMembers()) {
        if(members.getRoles().contains(role)) {
            sendPrivateMessage(members.getUser(), "Hello <@!" + members.getId() + ">"); // Sends infinitely
        }
    }
```

sendPrivateMessage():

```
public void sendPrivateMessage(User user, String content) {
    user.openPrivateChannel()
            .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(content))
            .queue();
}
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me, may we see the function `sendPrivateMessage(user, message)`?

Comment: `public void sendPrivateMessage(User user, String content) {
    user.openPrivateChannel()
            .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(content))
            .queue();
}`

Comment: So if I am correct, the code is in the function `MessageReceivedEvent()`? If so, that means every time there is _any_ message in the gulild your bot is in, regardless of  which text channel, it will send a DM to everyone if they have a specific role. Is this what you wanted?

Also: Please consider editing your post and putting the code for the function `sendPrivateMessage(user, message)` there, so it will be easier to read.

Comment: instead of `<@!" + members.getId() + ">"`, you can use `members.getAsMention()` and let JDA deal with that for you. So you don't have to worry even if that changes in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
public void sendPrivateMessage(User user, String content) {
    if (user.isBot()) return;

    user.openPrivateChannel()
        .flatMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(content))
        .queue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if this code gets executed in the MessageReceivedEvent you may try adding

```
if(event.getAuthor().isBot()){
return;
}
```

so that it wont reply itself if you haven't already.
(If you want it to answer to other bots, you can also use the JDA, to get the selfUser and check if this event got executed by itself)
If thats not the case maybe you could tell us more about when it gets executed.